# Date fill with data for all rows based on last entry date in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset where table1 has the date and name, I want to do a date fill and populate the name column with the most recent previous date value. Do this until current date

I am sure I must use lag function and left join / join with a table2 that just have dates. But unsure on how to proceed

This is how the input looks like

**Table1**

[image]

**Table2**

[image]

This is the expected output

[image]

Expansion of current request

[image]

Comment: How did you come up with 9/28/2022 in the output?

Comment: that should be filled till the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no *need* to use a window function here. For each entry in table1 you need the date of the entry that chronologically comes next. That is the minimum date which is greater than the date of the current record:

```
SELECT dt, (SELECT min(dt) FROM table1 WHERE dt > cur.dt) as next, name 
  FROM table1 cur;
```

Of course, you *can* use a window function:

```
SELECT dt, lag(dt) over (order by dt desc) as next, name 
  FROM table1 cur;
```

For the most recent entry, next will be `NULL`, so you want to COALESCE the value with e. g. the current date. Then, you can join the result with your second table:

```
SELECT t2.dt, t1.name
  FROM (SELECT dt, 
               COALESCE((SELECT min(dt) FROM table1 WHERE dt > cur.dt), date(now())) as next, 
               name 
          FROM table1 cur) t1
 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON t2.dt BETWEEN t1.dt AND t1.next;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I see that it stops updating when it comes to the latest date - I mean the lastest date and its corresponding name is not update till current date

Comment: Since I am using databricks- I get an error when I use the min logic -

Comment: Correlated column is not allowed in a non-equality predicate: is the error

Comment: Regarding the date: that might be the case if you expect the dates not to be in UTC, because now() probably returns the current date/time in UTC. E. g. if you call now() in Berlin at 2022-09-29 00:30, you'll get 2022-09-28 22:30. You'd have to convert the time zone, e. g. `date(convert_tz(now(), '+00:00', '+02:00'))` to convert from UTC to UTC+02:00. Regarding databricks (whatever this is): use the window function :-)

Comment: Oh yes! I used current_date() and it works! Thank you so much

Comment: Do you know How I can expand this code when the same dataset but with multiple IDs are given?

Comment: I've seen that you updated your question but it's unclear where the ID's come from.

Comment: The original dataset has three columns id, dt and name - Each id has its own records of date and names

Comment: So, If I am trying to date fill, I would have to iterate this code over every id I have

Comment: You can try `select t2.dt, t1.id, t1.name from (select id, dt, lag
(dt) over (order by id, dt desc) as next, name from table1)
t1 inner join table2 t2 on t2.dt between t1.dt and t1.next order by id, dt;`

Comment: Yes I tried this, select
  t2.dt,
  t1.id,
  t1.name
from
  (
    select
      id,
      dt,
      COALESCE(lag(dt) over (order by id, dt desc), current_date()) as next,
      name
    from
      table1
  ) t1
  inner join table2 t2 on t2.dt between t1.dt
  and t1.next
order by
  id,
  dt;

Comment: But it isnt print my current date -> latest date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248480/discussion-between-mihe-and-yash).

Comment: Do you know how I can handle this same logic if there are multiple names on the same day
I want each entry for every day and then date fill them to the current date
Currently, it only takes one of the names and does the date filling

Comment: I think the logic lies where we use the lag function. Say on 12-7 someone has a name and changed to another name, next change was on 12-9. Ideally I need a row that says 12-7 - 12-9 name 1 and 12-7 to 12-9 name2

Comment: Could you post a new question? This thread ist starting to get messy.